# Why does this Jquery If statement not work?

Tags: jquery

I have a statement like this:

I have already double checked the ids of the related html elements. If I remove the if statement everything works ok. Do you have any idea why does not it work?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ok").click(function() {

                $('#ok').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                //global vars                     
                var ad = $("#ad").val().length;  

                    If (ad < 6) {
                    alert("you must enter a higher value");
                    }

                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that "ad" is probably never less than six, or else it would work. It's hard to tell without more code.

Comment: `If` isn't the same as `if`.

Comment: In javascript, `if` is lowercase.

Comment: `#ok` is the id of my submit button.

Comment: You're right. I typed `If` instead of `if`. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing either you should lowercase your "if".  The problem is obviously not a type-related issue.

And to clarify via a comment on the question and an answer below:

```
If (ad < 6) {
```

should be

```
if (ad < 6) {
```

This is the case because Javascript is case-sensitive.  I would very much like to thank all who were involved in this and I hope there is no more confusion about anything related to this issue.

Comment: It's the `If`.  JavaScript is case sensitive; it must be `if`.

Comment: How could he have a type problem?

Comment: Don't know, baz.  Guess it's pretty illogical in this case.  On the other hand, I have an extremely little code sample and guessed what the problem was.  Whoops?

Comment: @dweiss The little code sample has `.length`, which is a number, and `6`, which seems to be a number either.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I agree.  In this code sample, as I very clearly stated, it is "pretty illogical" for the issue to be type-related.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive so your if must be all lowercase, try this

```
 if (ad < 6) {
     alert("you must enter a higher value");
 }
```

Comment: Ash -- I posted this as an answer, then a minute later Jonathan put this as a comment.  As this was already posted as both an answer and later a comment, I don't think there's any reason it needs to be posted as an answer a second time.

Comment: @dweiss I think this answer is better quality. I don't understand the downvote. +1

Comment: Better...quality?  You do realize we're talking about "If" becoming "if" right?

Comment: @dweiss, your answer states nothing about the reason why it is incorrect which mine does.

Comment: @dweiss In your answer, you're guessing around, mention two things one of which is nonsense. Then ask for more code (so the whole thing looks more like a comment). This answer clearly states that Javascript is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: YOU'RE ABSOLUTELY CORRECT!!!  On the other hand, there's this cool, neat, nifty little comment just underneath my answer which explains it.  And then again in the comments.

Comment: Ash -- I think if I say "If" doesn't work but "if" does work, then there's a bit of an implication there.  I do think the comment in my answer is totally valuable because it clearly states which of my two guesses is accurate.  And it says "Javascript is case sensitive"

Comment: @dweiss You're always free to improve your answer (I do it a lot). The site and all of us benefit from having better answers.

Comment: @dweiss, the reason for answering posts is not only to solve the OP's problem but also to help future visitors to the site. I would bet that the majority of people looking for answers to their problems look more an answers than comments. As baz said, answers should be updated to incorporate comments where they would be of benefit to future visitors.